# Is sessionAffinity not working with LoadBalancer on GCE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have small nodejs app running replicated with two pods on cluster with two nodes.

However, it seems that connection is not sticky. I need it to be sticky because I use websocket.

Is sessionAffinity not working with LoadBalancer on GCE? Let me know if i can provide more info. Thanks

---

Finally I had some time for more experiments:

It seems like the sessionAffinity stops working if the rc is deleted and created again after the service was created.

Steps to reproduce:

- 1) Used following files:

ServerName.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: servername
  labels:
    name: servername
spec:
  replicas: 10
  selector:
    name: servername
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: servername
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app
        image:  fibheap/printhostname
        imagePullPolicy: "Always"
        ports:
             - containerPort: 80
```

ServerNameSv.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: servername
  labels:
    name: servername
spec:
  ports:
    # the port that this service should serve on
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    name: servername
  type: LoadBalancer
  sessionAffinity: ClientIP
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM google/nodejs

WORKDIR /app

ADD ./main.js /app/main.js

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["node", "--harmony", "./main.js"]
```

main.js

```
// Load the http module to create an http server.
var http = require('http');
var os = require('os');

// Configure our HTTP server to respond with Hello World to all requests.
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] ||
     req.connection.remoteAddress ||
     req.socket.remoteAddress ||
     req.connection.socket.remoteAddress;

  res.end("CIP:" + ip + "  Remote Server:" + os.hostname());
});

// Listen on port 8000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
server.listen(80);

// Put a friendly message on the terminal
console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:80/");
```

---

- 2) create rc and service (describe service to get IP and assure ClientIP is set)
- 3) curl multiple times from loadbalancer ip -> pod name should stay the same
- 4) delete rc and create again
- 5) curl again multiple time -> pod name changes

Please let me know if that helps for reproducing. Please feel free to use docker repository fibheap/printhostname directly

Comment: It seems like the sessionAffinity stops working if the rc is deleted and created again after the service was created.  Edited original post to include an example.

Answer (score 0):

Affinity should work.  Can you read back your service object and see that affinity was accepted and saved properly?

kubectl get svc app-service

I just created a GCE load balancer, and I confirmed that the GCE targetPool object also has

sessionAffinity: CLIENT_IP

Answer (score 0):

As concluded in https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/36415, sessionAffinity on GCE will probably only work if you make your service a LoadBalanceer with "preserve client ip", i.e.  `"service.beta.kubernetes.io/external-traffic": "OnlyLocal"`, and you set `sessionAffinity=ClientIP`.

Ingress is probably a better bet. I haven't verified this, but Nginx Ingress will bypass services and there's a "sticky-ng" module.